# strtok return string?

Tags: c, token, delimiter, strtok, strcmp

just having a little issue with strtok and strcmp.

I'm trying to compare the input of a user via fgets to some predetermined string:

```
char *token[100];

fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin)
token[0] = strtok(s, " "); // Get first word
printf("tok: %s", token[0]);
printf("cmp: %d\n", strcmp(token[0], "/bin/echo");
```

Obviously it's not all the code but this shows my problem - if I enter "/bin/echo ..." (or anything for that matter), it will be put into token[0], and get printed. It prints correctly but when it prints the cmp value it's never 0. For /bin/echo, the cmp value is 1 for some reason.

Thanks.

EDIT to clear up confusion about s and token:

```
char s[1024];
char *token[100];
```

EDIT 2 - Added some other test cases:
I entered "/bin/echo hello world" to stdin

```
token[0] = strtok(s, " \n\0"); // Get first word
printf("token[0] is: %s", token[0]);
printf("cmp: %d\n", strcmp(token[0], "/bin/echo"));
```

Output:

```
token[0] is: /bin/echo
cmp: 1
```

And then I tried hardcoding the tokened string:

```
char str[] = "/bin/echo hello world";
token[0] = strtok(str, " ");
printf("token[0] is: %s", token[0]);
printf("cmp: %d\n", strcmp(token[0], "/bin/echo"));
```

Output:

```
token[0] is: /bin/echo
cmp: 0
```

Comment: We can start with code that compiles. (missing semi after `fgets()`, no declaration of `s`, missing closing paren on second `printf()`, just to name the ones I see arbitrarily). The real piece missing, though, is `s`. It better be a valid memory buffer of some kind.

Comment: That said, I fixed, and ran, this code, declaring `s` as a local buffer `char s[100];` and ran the code with  input as "/bin/echo madness". it ran fine and reported `0` as the compare result, so whatever your problem is, this code isn't exhibiting it (beyond the compilation errors, anyway).

Comment: I suspect you enter _only_ `"/bin/echo"`. Then you get the token `"/bin/echo\n"` since `fgets` includes the newline.

Comment: @WhozCraig Cleared up the confusion about s. To you and Daniel, I also just tried with a string[] and it works, so I have no idea why getting it from an input buffer stdin wouldn't work either, unless I'm missing a delimiter as posted down below somewhere.

Comment: With your code fixed and including the defs you added, it should work, though I would add `\n` in the delimiter string in case someone enters just the command with no params.

Comment: Yep- I added \n as a delimiter, but still no cigar :(

Comment: Look at Mr.32's answer below. he even has a live-demo for you to check out. Likewise, **[here is one as well](http://ideone.com/TfEyn3)**.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yup, I've explored it and added it to the original post, only problem is I can't just hardcode the string, needs to be a user input. Take a look at the post for my results on the matter.

Comment: **[Look at the sample I linked again](http://ideone.com/TfEyn3)**. Those aren't hard-coded. It pulls from stdin.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh, sorry. I just had a look at Mr.32's only, and completely ignored yours. Just changed a few snippets of my code (although it already looked quite similar) and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: you realize the suspense of where they *differed*, not where they were *similar* is going to eat at me for the rest of the day, right? Whatever that difference was, it was why yours did not work, so perhaps share that.

Comment: @Travv92 look at my post for working example

Answer (score 1):

here i have made small program

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
char str[] ="/bin/echo this is something";
  char * token[100];
  token[0] = strtok (str," ");

token[0] = strtok(str, " "); // Get first word
printf("cmp: %d\n", strcmp(token[0], "/bin/echo"));
return 0;
}
```

Here i have statically stored input string instead of fgets()

That works fine.

see http://codepad.org/IrGAXT8f

Comment: Just tried this and it works - only problem is I need to get the input from command line stdin, so hard coding the str[] wont work unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
char token[1000];
strcpy(token,strtok(s," "));
```

string's can't be assigned directly like this in c :)

also, include string.h

Comment: This is not just wrong, its wrong at the top of its voice. Read [`strtok()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)s documentation, then look at the *type* of the token **pointer array**.

Comment: One can't copy strings to uninitialized memory. You need need to allocate memory first.

Comment: @user206334 One need not copy strings *at all* if you understand `strtok()` and what it returns.

Comment: @WhozCraig strtok messes with buffer adding '\0' in delimiter places as a future marker. That's why it's not const char * and you can't use strtok with static memory objects like literal strings.

Comment: @user206334 that's somewhat the point of the function of [`strtok()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok). That isn't the problem the OP is having, and from what I see, has nothing to do with this answer or its incorrectness.

Comment: OP, use strncpy() to be safe.

Comment: Sorry about the fact, missed that he hadn't allocated the memory. And I was just pointing out the fact that the string was assigned with =.

Comment: @WhozCraig the function of strtok is to provide pointer to the first element, the side effect of implementation is that alters original buffer. I usually memcpy provided buffer to be safe that I do not alter buffer stored in static memory.

Comment: @user206334 `strtok()`'s modification of the host buffer is no side-effect. It is by design. If the original buffer is not to be modified (such as a const char*, which wont' even compile) a copy must be made *prior* to `strtok()` initialization with the copy buffer tokenized; not the original. But since we know nothing about `s`... we can only hope it was a proper buffer, though if the rest of the code is any indicator, I wouldn't put much stock in that either.

Answer (score -1):

One needs to allocate memory dynamically for copying strings. Read about dynamic memory management first (malloc, calloc, etc...)

**EDIT:**
http://ideone.com/0UxEwO - works for me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[1024];
    char *token[100];
    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
    token[0] = strtok(s, " \n\0");
    printf("token[0] is: %s", token[0]);
    printf("cmp: %d\n", strcmp(token[0], "/bin/echo"));
}
```

Comment: Downvoter please explain how did s get allocated? One either needs to statically specify array size or dynamically allocate memory. One can't simply use char * s = fgets(...).

Comment: I didn't down-vote this, but where do you see the OP using `char *s = fgets(...)` ? The lack of any `s` is one of the many things wrong with the code, but nothing says it *must* be dynamically allocated. It could just as well be a stack var.

Comment: Sorry, probably should've shown s and token being initialized. Added to OP.